# Using MSXML2.XMLHTTP in MS Access VBA Returning Blank Body Response

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access application that sends a unique identifier to a webpage, and the page is SUPPOSED to respond with First Name, Last Name, and DOB.

This recently broke, and my best trace at root cause is that the request is returning a blank body from the webpage, and our code uses the body to parse out the returned data. No body, no parsing.

There are NO errors as I step through the code. A coworker and I have a combined 3 days fighting with this. We've found the breaking points, but no leads on fixing it.

Here's an outline of what's supposed to happen, and details on where troubleshooting has led us:

1. On Click of "Lookup Button" on Access form, Validate ID Number Format

```vba
    Dim sHTML as String
    If ValidIDFormat(Me.ID.Value & "") Then
        sHTML = GetDOCData(Me.ID.Value)
```

(I'll spare you the code behind "ValidIDFormat" as that's not the source of the issue)

2. GetDocData (above) is (I think?) the issue. GetDocData is a function that takes the ID Number and sends it as a request to the webpage as follows:

```vba
    Public Function GetDOCData(aID As String) As String
    Const SUB_NAME As String = "GetDOCData"
    On Error GoTo ErrCond
    Dim myurl As String
    Dim t As Single
    Dim TimedOut As Boolean
    Dim Tries As Integer
    
    Dim xHTTP As MSXML2.xmlhttp
    Set xHTTP = New MSXML2.xmlhttp
    myurl = "http://doclookup.com/GCA00P00/WIQ1/WINQ000"  'Upon inspecting the webpage, I found /GCA00P00/WIQ1/WINQ000 corresponds to the webpage's Form Method "Post" Action ( <form method="post" action="/GCA00P00/WIQ1/WINQ000"> )
TryAgain:
    xHTTP.Open "POST", myurl, True
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "max-age=0"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "213"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Host", "doclookup.com"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Origin", "http://doclookup.com"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Proxy-Connection", "keep-alive"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Referer", "http://doclookup.com/GCA00P00/WIQ1/WINQ000"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"
    xHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xHTTP.send "K01=WINQ000&DFH_STATE_TOKEN=&DFH_MAP_STATE_TOKEN=&M00_LAST_NAMEI=&M00_FIRST_NAMEI=&M00_MID_NAMEI=&M00_NAME_SUFXI=&M00_DOBCCYYI=&M00_ID_FLD1I=" & left(aID, 2) & "&M00_ID_FLD2I=" & Mid(aID, 3, 1) & "&M00_ID_FLD3I=" & Right(aID, 4) & "&M00_MISCID_FLD1I=&M00_MISCID_FLD2I="
    t = Timer
    Tries = 1
    Do While (True)
        DoEvents
        If ((Timer - t) > 5) Then
            TimedOut = True
            xHTTP.abort
            GetDOCData = ""
            Exit Do
        End If
        If (xHTTP.ReadyState = 4) Then
            If (xHTTP.Status <> 200) Then
                If (Tries < 3) Then
                    Tries = Tries + 1
                    xHTTP.abort
                    GoTo TryAgain
                Else
                    TimedOut = True
                    xHTTP.abort
                    GetDOCData = ""
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Else
                TimedOut = False
                GetDOCData = xHTTP.responseText
                Debug.Print xHTTP.responseText
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set xHTTP = Nothing
    Exit Function
ErrCond:
    EventLogging AppSession.UserName, MSG_TYPE_ERROR, Err.Number, Err.Description, MOD_NAME & "." & SUB_NAME, AppSession.AppSilent
    Set xHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Debug.Print output of the response:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="/>

<script>

(function(){
window["bobcmn"] = "11111110101010200000005200000005200000001282ff3ca2200000096300000029application%2fx%2dwww%2dform%2durlencoded300000000300000006/TSPD/300000008TSPD_101300000004http3000000b008f09154e8ab2000c866a39c833f24d99d84e7901aac5a13c0c8ad737654afb25b96b27aba9f9b9008c421cc190a28006d5c954f4b5b362cf850d4f70b2a1ff8e8fcfb526acb91a5740a4c0e36f7d3e7e790a51f2ffbaf98300000107K01%3dWINQ000%26DFH_STATE_TOKEN%3d%26DFH_MAP_STATE_TOKEN%3d%26M00_LAST_NAMEI%3d%26M00_FIRST_NAMEI%3d%26M00_MID_NAMEI%3d%26M00_NAME_SUFXI%3d%26M00_DOBCCYYI%3d%26M00_ID_FLD1I%3d95%26M00_ID_FLD2I%3db%26M00_ID_FLD3I%3d1929%26M00_MISCID_FLD1I%3d%26M00_MISCID_FLD2I%3d200000000";

window.OYm=!!window.OYm;try{(function(){(function(){var S={decrypt:function(S){try{return JSON.parse(function(S){S=S.split("l");var I="";for(var l=0;l<S.length;++l)I+=String.fromCharCode(S[l]);return I}(S))}catch(l){}}};return S={configuration:S.decrypt("123l34l97l99l116l105l118l101l34l58l34l110l111l34l44l34l100l101l98l117l103l103l105l110l103l34l58l34l110l111l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l49l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l50l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l51l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l44l34l109l111l100l117l108l101l52l34l58l34l101l110l97l98l108l101l100l34l125")}})();
var iS=91;try{var JS,LS,OS=_(200)?0:1,ZS=_(567)?0:1,S_=_(300)?0:1;for(var __=(_(912),0);__<LS;++__)OS+=_(989)?1:2,ZS+=(_(404),2),S_+=(_(437),3);JS=OS+ZS+S_;window.jj===JS&&(window.jj=++JS)}catch(i_){window.jj=JS}var o_=!0;function J(S){var I=arguments.length,l=[];for(var Z=1;Z<I;++Z)l.push(arguments[Z]-S);return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,l)}
function z_(S){var I=69;!S||document[L(I,187,174,184,174,167,174,177,174,185,190,152,185,166,185,170)]&&document[J(I,187,174,184,174,167,174,177,174,185,190,152,185,166,185,170)]!==J(I,187,174,184,174,167,177,170)||(o_=!1);return o_}function L(S){var I=arguments.length,l=[],Z=1;while(Z<I)l[Z-1]=arguments[Z++]-S;return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,l)}function _i(){}z_(window[_i[O(1086763,iS)]]===_i);z_(typeof ie9rgb4!==O(1242178186108,iS));
z_(RegExp("\x3c")[O(1372114,iS)](function(){return"\x3c"})&!RegExp(O(42798,iS))[O(1372114,iS)](function(){return"'x3'+'d';"}));
var ii=window[L(iS,188,207,207,188,190,195,160,209,192,201,207)]||RegExp(J(iS,200,202,189,196,215,188,201,191,205,202,196,191),O(-73,iS))[O(1372114,iS)](window["\x6e\x61vi\x67a\x74\x6f\x72"]["\x75\x73e\x72A\x67\x65\x6et"]),ji=+new Date+(_(283)?392128:6E5),Ji,li,si,SI=window[J(iS,206,192,207,175,196,200,192,202,208,207)],iI=ii?_(896)?24437:3E4:_(789)?7473:6E3;
document[L(iS,188,191,191,160,209,192,201,207,167,196,206,207,192,201,192,205)]&&document[L(iS,188,191,191,160,209,192,201,207,167,196,206,207,192,201,192,205)](L(iS,209,196,206,196,189,196,199,196,207,212,190,195,188,201,194,192),function(S){var I=87;document[L(I,205,192,202,192,185,192,195,192,203,208,170,203,184,203,188)]&&(document[J(I,205,192,202,192,185,192,195,192,203,208,170,203,184,203,188)]===O(1058781896,I)&&S[J(I,192,202,171,201,204,202,203,188,187)]?si=!0:document[J(I,205,192,202,192,
185,192,195,192,203,208,170,203,184,203,188)]===L(I,205,192,202,192,185,195,188)&&(Ji=+new Date,si=!1,II()))});function II(){if(!document[J(33,146,150,134,147,154,116,134,141,134,132,149,144,147)])return!0;var S=+new Date;if(S>ji&&(_(848)?582451:6E5)>S-Ji)return z_(!1);var I=z_(li&&!si&&Ji+iI<S);Ji=S;li||(li=!0,SI(function(){li=!1},_(257)?0:1));return I}II();var jI=[_(425)?18598439:17795081,_(80)?2147483647:27611931586,_(166)?1983416588:1558153217];
function JI(S){var I=35;S=typeof S===O(1743045641,I)?S:S[J(I,151,146,118,151,149,140,145,138)](_(696)?24:36);var l=window[S];if(!l[L(I,151,146,118,151,149,140,145,138)])return;var Z=""+l;window[S]=function(S,I){li=!1;return l(S,I)};window[S][J(I,151,146,118,151,149,140,145,138)]=function(){return Z}}for(var LI=(_(728),0);LI<jI[L(iS,199,192,201,194,207,195)];++LI)JI(jI[LI]);z_(!1!==window[J(iS,170,180,200)]);window.IJ={Ll:"08d706d6c9018000e5822dadf90337bb593587216c9ab6a9c485b83578c4437a79e29efc9f34e830ff2af64ab8efa8fb630e6dd1e0826eb0daddd2bd5edfb2a1b1e82309950dfc445dbcd7cec14c66aad4477867c752f7bbeff0a97475a6bb1261632c2feef07f430cba4664d7e896295e4276a6c7e8e1303b350f2e5189a8f59b760816d0b62a13"};function O(S,I){S+=I;return S.toString(36)}
function oI(S){var I=+new Date,l;!document[J(46,159,163,147,160,167,129,147,154,147,145,162,157,160,111,154,154)]||I>ji&&(_(911)?801408:6E5)>I-Ji?l=z_(!1):(l=z_(li&&!si&&Ji+iI<I),Ji=I,li||(li=!0,SI(function(){li=!1},_(609)?0:1)));return!(arguments[S]^l)}function _(S){return 55>S}(function zI(I){I&&"number"!==typeof I||("number"!==typeof I&&(I=1E3),I=Math.max(I,1),setInterval(function(){zI(I-10)},I))})(!0);})();}catch(x){}finally{ie9rgb4=void(0);};function ie9rgb4(a,b){return a>>b>>0};

})();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/08f09154e8ab20002596bec38bbab41a56da7004c2247af39c737e1fdd1f8257d17ddc6579566094?type=10"></script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.<br/>Your support ID is:  1436304770756522234.</noscript>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

We noticed there is NOTHING returned between the "body" tags in the last 2 lines above ...

I also note the "Please enable JavaScript..." message, before the empty tags. However, if this is the root issue, I'm unaware of how to enable JS in VBA. I tried researching this, and couldn't find anything helpful.

Between #2 and #3 is where the disconnect occurs:

3. Take webpage response (above) and check if ID that was entered in Access correlates to 1, or multiple records for this person - housed in this website.

```vba
    If (IsSingleID(sHTML)) Then     '  "sHTML" here is the returned string from the webpage response in "GetDocData" Function above 
    Person = ParseDOCRecord(Me.ID.Value, sHTML)

'sometimes there are multiple returned values - housed in the website - for the person in question. One person can have multiple records, each given a unique ID. There's a different section of code, and different parsing, if multiple records/multiple IDs are returned.
```

IsSingleID is a Function defined as follows

```vba
    Public Function IsSingleID(aHTML As String) As Boolean
    Const SUB_NAME As String = "IsSingleID"
    On Error GoTo ErrCond
    Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim o As Variant
    IsSingleID = False
    doc.Body.innerHTML = aHTML
    For Each o In doc.getElementsByTagName("h2")
        If (Trim(o.innerText) = "Person Information") Then
            IsSingleID = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set doc = Nothing
    Exit Function
ErrCond:
    EventLogging AppSession.UserName, MSG_TYPE_ERROR, Err.Number, Err.Description, MOD_NAME & "." & SUB_NAME, AppSession.AppSilent
End Function
```

The code EXITS here! There is no "o" in in doc.getElementsByTagName("h2")
Could this be because " doc.Body.innerHTML = aHTML " returns a Blank body?

I tried adding a watch to "aHTML" variable to confirm what part(s) of the webpage response (sHTML) is/are sent to "aHTML" variable in above function. But the variable/response was too long for the Watch window.

Regardless, the run never reaches the "ParseDOCRecord" Function in:

```vba
    If (IsSingleID(sHTML)) Then    
    Person = ParseDOCRecord(Me.ID.Value, sHTML)
```

The run EXITS "IsSingleID" function, returns to "Lookup Button" Function (#1), and drops to a 'catch all' kind of message box, hard coded to return:

```vba
MsgBox "Unable to get information from DOC site."
```

I'm scratching my head on this.

Troubleshooting steps we've tried:

We tried updating references to Microsoft XML,v6.0 and using MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 instead. My reasoning was maybe there was a change to the older library that was picked up in the latest version.

Tried removing "/GCA00P00/WIQ1/WINQ000" from the URL, and simply using "doclookup.com"

Tried replacing "h2" tag with "form" tag, in doc.getElementsByTagName("h2") because I noticed I didn't see an "h2" tag in the inspected webpage

Here is the code from Form section of the webpage:

```html
<form method="post" action="/GCA00P00/WIQ1/WINQ000">
    <div class="border">
      <input type="hidden" name="K01" value="WINQ000">
      <input type="hidden" name="DFH_STATE_TOKEN" value="adyqlisv">
      <input type="hidden" name="DFH_MAP_STATE_TOKEN" value="">
      <div class="pair">
        <label for="M00_LAST_NAMEI">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" size="18" maxlength="18" name="M00_LAST_NAMEI" value="" id="M00_LAST_NAMEI">
      </div>
      <div class="pair">
        <label for="M00_FIRST_NAMEI">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" size="11" maxlength="11" name="M00_FIRST_NAMEI" value="" id="M00_FIRST_NAMEI">
      </div>
      <div class="pair">
        <label for="M00_MID_NAMEI">Middle Init:</label>
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" name="M00_MID_NAMEI" value="" id="M00_MID_NAMEI">
      </div>
      <div class="pair">
        <label for="M00_NAME_SUFXI">Name Suffix:</label>
        <input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" name="M00_NAME_SUFXI" value="" id="M00_NAME_SUFXI"> (SR, JR, etc.)
      </div>
      <div class="pair">
        <label for="M00_DOBCCYYI">Birth Year:</label>
        <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" name="M00_DOBCCYYI" value="" id="M00_DOBCCYYI"> (Optional, see above)
      </div>
      <div class="pair">
        <label for="M00_DIN_FLD1I">DIN:<span class="hide"> Two digit number
         </span></label>
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="M00_ID_FLD1I" value="" id="M00_DIN_FLD1I" onfocus="select()" onkeyup="KeyPress(this,event,2,'WINQM00.form.M00_DIN_FLD2I.focus()')">
        -
        <label for="M00_DIN_FLD2I" class="hide">One character alpha</label>
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" name="M00_ID_FLD2I" value="" id="M00_DIN_FLD2I" onfocus="select()" onkeyup="KeyPress(this,event,1,'WINQM00.form.M00_DIN_FLD3I.focus()')">
        -
        <label for="M00_DIN_FLD3I" class="hide">Four digit number</label>
        <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" name="M00_ID_FLD3I" value="" id="M00_DIN_FLD3I" onfocus="select()">
         (ID Number, format 99-A-9999, example 95-A-9876)
      </div>
      <div class="pair">
        <label for="M00_NYSID_FLD1I">NYSID:<span class="hide"> Eight digit
         number</span></label>
        <input type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" name="M00_MISCID_FLD1I" value="" id="M00_MISCID_FLD1I" onfocus="select()" onkeyup="KeyPress(this,event,8,'WINQM00.form.M00_MISCID_FLD2I.focus()')">
        -
        <label for="M00_MISCID_FLD2I" class="hide">One character alpha</label>
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" name="M00_MISCID_FLD2I" value="" id="M00_MISCID_FLD2I" onfocus="select()">
         (For InterDepartmental Use Only; MISC ID Number)
      </div>
      <div class="aligncenter ">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript: location.href = location.href;" value="Reset">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

What am I missing?

I hope I've explained this with the right amount of detail...

How can I get this request to return data again?

---

Follow up based on comments/comment threads below...

I did a search for a record on the website (not one within the application) in order to generate response log from Network tab of webpage. DIN # 18B3079 screenshot of response as follows:[image: Response Header of Lookup]

Comment: Is this a paid for service or can Joe Public interact with the website and repro this issue? I assume the website has updated the search mechanism. You need to test performing this with the actual website and look for which request actually returns the content and any preceding ones that may be required and try and repro those.

Comment: This might be a dumb suggestion, but have you looked at the text in `XHTTP.XML` instead of `XHTTP.responsetext`?

Comment: Is that the real URL?  Can you post a working URL for the search form you're trying to mimic?

Comment: @QHarr - this is a public website that anyone can get to. I obfuscated it for the sake of keeping information general. I'm also assuming something changed with the website but since it's not one I maintain, and we took for granted the years that everything worked without a hitch, there's no way for me to trace that theory.

Comment: @Toddleson - I'll look into that right now!

Comment: @TimWilliams - the website is http://nysdoccslookup.doccs.ny.gov/

Comment: is there a unique id we can test with?

Comment: If I do a name search the page does a multi-part form POST.

Comment: @QHarr for privacy purposes, I can't disclose any records I'm actually dealing with. What I can offer is the format that the website uses (something more publicly available)
https://doccs.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2020/11/4007.pdf 
##-a-#### where ## is 2 digit year, a is a single alphabet character designated in the above PDF, and #### is a 4 digit number that increments sequentially (also explained in the linked document)

Comment: Understood. Now, when you examine performing a DIN (?) search in the network tab do you also see a multi-form POST request made? As the code you show above does not appear to be performing such a request.

Comment: @QHarr - apologies for the delay, I'm out of office on the weekend. Can you walk me through that a little bit? Where is the Network tab I should be observing when I do a search? I use Chrome.

Comment: @QHarr - I do know that there is a Form Post request done. Not a multi form post, from what I can tell of the site's code.

Comment: @QHarr - I found the Network tab. The first response header does mention POST and something about ajax. Is there a way I can add screenshots? Should I add to the original question?

Comment: You can add screenshots but be careful not to display parts that you might want to obscure

Comment: @QHarr - this will be the code from Network tab of website. So all public domain. I'll add those to the original question in a few moments.

Comment: Yes but if you show the body of the POST request it will show the search param you entered i.e., any id

Comment: @QHarr - I'll do some last name searches, to find a DIN that's not a record I'm working with ... good point!

Comment: @QHarr - I've added the DIN I used (not one contained within the internal application) and the response header from the Network tab.

Comment: Need to see the POST body and headers though doesn't matter as you included the DIN so I can replicate my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235068/discussion-between-qharr-and-junipersquared).